# Scheduling a RichCopy Jobs

Tags: file, copy

Anyone use the timer feature of RichCopy? I have a job that works fine when I manually start the job. However, when I schedule the job and click run, the app appears to be waiting for the scheduled time to elapse yet never fires. Interesting enough when I stop the job the copy starts.

Anyone have any experience with using RichCopy timer?

IanB

Comment: Still looking for some help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try created a batch file with command line options.  Then use windows scheduler to launch the batch.

Comment: This is the method I am currenty using. I was looking to see if the timer feature was usable. 

While not the answer to the question, I think this is the correct protocol.

Thanks for your imput.

Answer (score -3):

OMBG (Bill Gates) You need to read and get security policy and the respect it has to place on a hierarchy of upstream objects and credentials.  Well that's the MS answer and attitude...

The reality is if you are working with server OSs you need to understand their security & policy frameworks, and how to debug them :).  If your process loses the necessary file permissions or rights (2 different things) you should ask: "Hot damn, why didn't I fix that in the config/setup". People that blast the vendor/project (or even @#@#&$! MS) are just blinding themselves to the solution/s.

In most cases this kind of issue is due to Windows' AD removing the rights of a Local administrator User to run a scheduled task.  It is a common security setting in corporate networks (implemented with glee by Domain Admins to upset developers) though it is really a default setting these days. It happens because the machine updates against an upstream policy (after you've scheduled a task) and decides that all of a sudden it won't trust you to run it (even though previously it let you set it up).  In a perfect world it wouldn't let you set it up in the first place, but that isn't the way policy applies in Windows... (@#@#&$! MS). LOL

Wow it only took 5 months to get an answer! (but here they are for the next person at least!)

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?